# How does casting a type in a function call work?

Tags: c, casting

Let's say I have something like the following to call a function in C:

```
void test1(void) {
    int a=7;
    function((short) a);
}
```

Does the compiler treat this (almost) the same as if it were to create a temporary variable and pass that to the function, for example:

```
void test1(void) {
    int a=7;
    short tmp_a=(short) a;
    function(tmp_a);
}
```

Or does the cast do anything differently than the above, at least on a conceptual level?

Comment: This is an implementation detail of the compiler.  The language only states that a conversion to the casted type is done.  Each compiler may do it differently, and one compiler may do it differently based on the setting it's passed.

Comment: @dbush: I do not see any implementation details there. Both sequences of code have the same observable behavior, and therefore the treatment of one by the compiler is the same as the treatment of the other by the compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Casts are just operators, like multiplication or shifts. When a function argument is an expression, it is evaluated like any other expression. So `function((short) a);` is equivalent to:

```
short tmp_a = (short) a;
function(tmp_a);
```

in the same way that `function(a*a);` is equivalent to:

```
int tmp_a = a*a;
function(tmp_a);
```

Note there are also implicit conversions involved in function calls. If the function has a prototype, arguments are converted to the declared types of the parameters. If there is no prototype, or an argument corresponds to the `...` part of a prototype, some default argument promotions are performed.